# (iOS) allow a 'parent' UIView to handle gestures before I do

Tags: ios, user-interface, swipe

I'm working on an iPad app that uses a custom GL View (written by another team, so we can't change their code), and I need to handle swipe gestures. However, it seems I've introduced a sluggishness into the GL View by installing my swipe handlers. Is there any way to tell that view to handle the gestures first?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:otherGestureRecognizer` method. Iterate through the gesture recognizers of you GL view and set `["GLViewRecognizer" requireGestureRecognizerToFail:"yourRecognizer"]`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail: